# PHP Select Form Not Populating: Undefined Index

Tags: php, html, sql, select

I am attempting to load some values from my SQL database based on my selected option value. However I am getting the following error.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<p>
<select id = "selectedValueG" name="selectedValueG">
<option value="Amphibians">Amphibians</option>
<option value="Birds">Birds</option>
<option value="Cnidarians">Cnidarians</option>
<option value="Fish">Fish</option>
<option value="Invertebrates">Invertebrates</option>
<option value="Reptiles">Reptiles</option>
</select>
</p>
<?php 
if ($_POST['selectedValueG'] == 'Amphibians'){
    $db->query("select [Common Name] FROM dbo.All_Animals WHERE [Group] = 'Amphibians'");
    $groupA = $db->fetch_all();
}
else if ($_POST['selectedValueG'] == 'Birds'){
    $db->query("select [Common Name] FROM dbo.All_Animals WHERE [Group] = 'Birds'");
    $groupA = $db->fetch_all();
}
else if ($_POST['selectedValueG'] == 'Cnidarians'){
    $db->query("select [Common Name] FROM dbo.All_Animals WHERE [Group] = 'Cnidarians'");
    $groupA = $db->fetch_all();
}
else if ($_POST['selectedValueG'] == 'Fish'){
    $db->query("select [Common Name] FROM dbo.All_Animals WHERE [Group] = 'Fish'");
    $groupA = $db->fetch_all();
}
else if ($_POST['selectedValueG'] == 'Invertebrates'){
    $db->query("select [Common Name] FROM dbo.All_Animals WHERE [Group] = 'Invertebrates'");
    $groupA = $db->fetch_all();
}
else if ($_POST['selectedValueG'] == 'Reptiles'){
    $db->query("select [Common Name] FROM dbo.All_Animals WHERE [Group] = 'Reptiles'");
    $groupA = $db->fetch_all();
}?>
 <p>
                          <label for="material">Common Name</label>
                          <select name="material" id="material">
                            <option>Select a Common Name:</option>
<?php
foreach($groupA as $m)
{
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $m['ID'];?>"><?php echo $m['Common Name'];?></option>
<?php
}
?>
```

Everything else is working fine except that I am getting the undefined index which is causing my second select statement(Common Name) not to populate.
Thank you for looking and answers!!!

Comment: Apparently `$_POST['selectedValueG']` is undefined. Are you sure the form was submitted with POST and not GET? Can you `print_r($_POST)` and examine it?

Comment: How you are post `selectedValueG` value. as you are not using form tag or jquery to send value based on onchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i guess you are populating the second dropdown from the first one, am i right?

If that's your case then use Ajax to populate the second dropdown,

```
var dataString = {first_combo_selected_value_here}
 $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "include/addfavorite.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
       $( "#material" ).append( html );
}
```

});

Second, why are you using all those conditionals? simply compare with the value as variable

```
$post_value = $_POST['selectedValueG'];
$db->query("select [Common Name] FROM dbo.All_Animals WHERE [Group] = '{$post_value}'");
$groupA = $db->fetch_all();
```

Comment: I like your compare with the value, and can I linked up jquery libraries into my .php page. Do I need to link Ajax libraries as well? Then just used a modified version of the code you provided above?

Comment: Just jQuery. no need to include any ajax library. yes you can use the code modified for your own need.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_POST['selectedValueG']
```

isn't set when the page loads.

Is there some more code somewhere else?  Is it supposed to be an AJAX form?

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the variable is set before accessing it (I assume you are submitting the form to get the value). Also, I think your code can be optimized. Try this:

```
$opt = array("Amphibians", "Birds", "Cnidarians", "Fish", "Invertebrates", "Reptiles");

if( isset($_POST["selectedValueG"]) )
{
    if( in_array($_POST["selectedValueG"], $os) )
    {
        $db->query("select [Common Name] FROM dbo.All_Animals WHERE [Group] = '".$_POST["selectedValueG"]."'");
        $groupA = $db->fetch_all();
    }
}
```

Does it work better? If not you can add a `print_r($_POST);` to see what variables are passed in your POST.